# How can I disable integrated terminal profiles that VS Code defines by default?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I click on new terminal I see all the shells available in my Windows 11 (powershell, ubuntu from WSL, gitbash, etc)

What I need is a configuration to remove / hide / disable the ones I don't use and only leave 1 or 2, that is, from the list, only keep Powershell and Ubuntu, instead of the 5 that appear.

The only settings asociate to terminal I have is:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "pwsh": {
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
      "args": ["-nologo"]
    }
  },
```

Here are the profiles that show up by default on Windows:

[image: new-terminal-vscode]

I need is a configuration to remove the ones I don't use.

I have been looking for information about this topic but I have not found how to achieve it.

UPDATE:

I solved with this:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": null,
    "Git Bash": null,
    "Command Prompt": null,
    "Ubuntu-20.04 (WSL)": null,
    "JavaScript Debug Terminal": null,
    "Windows PowerShell": null,

    "pwsh": {
      "path": "pwsh.exe",
      "args": ["-nologo"],
      "name": "pwsh"
    },
    "bash": {
      "path": ["C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\bash.exe"],
      "name": "bash"
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "bash",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that VS Code will always *merge in* the default-defined terminal profiles to the final list of profile definitions and that you can't stop it from doing that.

What you can do is just redefine them either to `null`, or set those fields to nothing.

For default profiles that use the `"path"` field, it will not show a profile option with `"path"` set to an empty array, or a path to something that doesn't exist.

For default profiles that support and use the `"source"` field instead of the `"path"` field, set the `"source"` field to `null`.

You can find the list of default terminal profile definitions in the default settings JSON file (use the `Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)`, and then use the editor search feature to search `terminal.integrated.profiles.`). Then just copy and paste it into your user or workspace settings.json file and adjust the values as described above.

Here's an example for my own Windows machine:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
        "source": null
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
        "source": null
    },
    "Ubuntu-20.04 (WSL)": {
        "path": []
    },
}
```

The other way to do it is this:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": null,
    "Command Prompt": null,
    "Git Bash": null,
    "Ubuntu-20.04 (WSL)": null,
    "JavaScript Debug Terminal": null,
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example? I've done that but they all keep showing up, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @PeterWagnerSandovalMoreno just edited to add example and found a missing piece.

Comment: thanks, I can solved with ur help, I edit my post